# Get Server URL at run time from Server Side in .NET 4 - SL4

Tags: .net, asp.net

Excuse my newbie question, but I´m working with Silverlight 4 at client side and .Net 4 at server side.

My issue is that, I want get at run time servers URL. Because now we are out of production but in a month we will install our system in the client servers, and we don´t want have anything static (example, server URL).

Example:
http://vwin-builder-01/ccars/#/ (that are server URL at builder)
http://localhost/CCARS/#/ (that are server URL at my local copy)

I mean?

Please, excuse my suxs english =)

I'll be waiting for your answers!!

Thanks for your time!

Fabian

Answer (score 1):

try `Application.Current.Host.Source.Host`

Comment: I cant access to Application.Current... on server side, this is for client side.

Comment: as far as i know you can't get the domain from the server side- it's configured somewhere else, and the asp.net website can't know it.